# Strech iframe and content at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe that the source is 640px x 400px. I would like to change the size of the iframe and the content at the same time.

The only way I managed to do that until now was using `transform.scale(...)` in css but using this method I can't choose the widht and height.

Comment: More information is needed. Can you control the iframe? Is the code resizing the iframe inside the iframe or in its parent? The content of an document is usually adapting to the size of its window, please elaborate "_size of the content_".